# Chrome extension to iterate all paragraphs in an HTML

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently my chrome extension is displaying a paragraph (first one), but wanted to iterate all paragraphs in an HTML and display those.

```
chrome.tabs.query( {
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
},
function(array_of_Tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);"}); 
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
   document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = request;
});
```

I wanted to add something like this in the above js. Pls advice.

```
let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  console.log(paragraphs[i].innerText) // Will print the content of each paragraph
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all the innerHTML's and message that.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
  },
  function(array_of_Tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
      code: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage([...document.getElementsByTagName('p')].reduce(function(agg, elem) {agg.push(elem.innerHTML); return agg; }, []).join("\n<br>"));`
    });
  });

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = request;
});
```

Comment: It didn't work and there is no error as well.

Comment: `var html` is empty.

Comment: I think i know why you need to inline it into 1 string of code. Code updated

Comment: sorry, it didn't help too.. somehow retrieving the paragraphs is empty.

Comment: it's an exact copy of your working code except one line (mine). try debugging it and focus on that line. for example add "zzz" + rest of string and see if that comes thru.

Comment: Worked, it just `.join("\n<br>` had some issue. By just adding `<br>` made a trick. Thank you!